# Sound does only work on Device but not in Simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, audio, audiotoolbox

I am playing some short sounds on my iPad like so: [Play a short sound in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329291/play-a-short-sound-in-ios/10336977#10336977)

I am using a `caf` file which I can successfully play from the Finder. Now I went through quite a bit of a hassle trying to achieve the playback of the sound and I am curious what might be the problems which I don't seem to understand:

- Option 1: When I create the SystemSoundID and then play it right away I don't hear anything on the device and the simulator.
- Option 2: When I create an instance variable for the SystemSoundID and initialize it in `viewDidLoad` I manage to play sound but only on the iPad, not the Simulator.
- Option 3: Instead of using `SystemSoundID` I can also use AVAudioPlayer to playback a `.wav` file which then works on both the iPad and the Simulator but here I need to create the AVAudioPlayer in `viewDidLoad` otherwise I won't get any sound if I do everything in one go.

The best option currently seems to be `Option 3` because it works on both the Simulator and the iPad, but because I need to pre-initialize the Player I would need an `AVAudioPlayer` instance for every different sound that I want to play, which does not seem to be very memory-wise...

Is there something that I am missing and is it possible to play sounds on both platforms using the `AudioToolbox` framework (Option 1 & Option 2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a library to simplify all this. It wraps AVAudioPlayer, and works fine on both the device and simulator.

https://github.com/nicklockwood/SoundManager

The code is fairly straightforward, although I do some semi-clever stuff to initialise the audio player. If you don't want to use the library you can just copy the code.

A word of warning though - the simulator throws some odd exceptions internally whenever you use AVAudioPlayer. They don't affect the app at all, but if you have enabled break-on-exceptions in Xcode then the app will drop into the debugger a few times during startup and you'll have to manually resume, which may freak you out if you're not expecting it.