# Play simple sound

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I need to play a sound when an action takes place, I already have the callback when the action ends and it's working fine and now I want to add a sound to it.
I've added `AudioToolbox` as framework and this is the code I tried to use:

```
SystemSoundID playSoundID;
NSURL *clockSound = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"clock" ofType:@"mp3"]];  //the path for my resource
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)clockSound, &playSoundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(playSoundID);
```

I don't get any errors but the sound isn't played

Comment: This looks pretty similar to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525942/play-audio-ios-objective-c

Comment: Objective-C is a language and can't play a sound by itself, so please refer to Foundation or AVAudio or whatever Apple framework you are using.

Comment: @idmean I believe at this moment of having Swift *and* Objective-C, it's valid to tag the questions with the used language. It may not be question regarding the language itself, but IMHO it helps filtering.

Comment: @Michal I was only referring to the title. I'm fine with the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AudioServicesPlaySystemSound()` function cannot play any MP3 files. The function supports only these file formats that are `.caf`, `.aac`, or `.wav` and the sound must be 30 seconds or less.

> Sound files that you play using this function must be:
>   No longer than 30 seconds in duration In linear PCM or IMA4 (IMA/ADPCM) format Packaged in a .caf, .aif, or .wav file

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioServicesPlaySystemSound

So if the `clock.mp3` is less than 30 seconds in duration, you can play the sound if convert the file format.

To convert `mp3` to `caf`, for example using `afconvert` command, like below:

```
$ afconvert -f caff -d ima4 clock.mp3 clock.caf
```

If not (the sound is more than 30 seconds), use `AVPlayer` of `AVFoundation.framework` instead. See the link of The Senator's comment.

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"m4a"];
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL  error:nil];
[player play];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
NSString *voice=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:TB_Voice_conversation_value];

NSError *error;
BOOL Errors;

AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
Errors = [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
Errors = [session  overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone error:&error];
[session setActive:YES error:nil];

NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],voice];
NSURL *soundUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];

_audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl error:nil];
if (!Errors)
{
    NSLog(@"Error:%@",error);
}
NSLog(@"session : %@",session);
[_audioPlayer play];
```