# convert url into NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata

I want to upload voice recording on server.

My file url is:

```
file:///Users/xantatech/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/77F4D768-1F04-4390-B60F-F1FE79388653/data/Containers/Data/Application/87C457FA-1A9F-4CA9-A651-6A3D411A0B7E/Documents/myAudio0.mp3
```

My Code is:

```
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:audioURL options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
```

But the data is nil.

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525942/play-audio-ios-objective-c

Comment: Try to use absoluteURL
`NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[audioURL absoluteURL]options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];`

Comment: Not worked, also nil occurs.

Comment: try `dataWithContentsOfFile`

Comment: I have also used.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code

```
NSString *audioURLString = @"file:///Users/xantatech/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/77F4D768-1F04-4390-B60F-F1FE79388653/data/Containers/Data/Application/87C457FA-1A9F-4CA9-A651-6A3D411A0B7E/Documents/myAudio0.mp3";
NSString *sendStr = [[audioURLString absoluteString] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"file:///private" withString:@""];
NSData *data = [[[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:sendStr]]];
```

Good luck.....

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for get data from Document folder:

```
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filepath)
{
   NSData *data = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:filepath];
}
else
{
   NSLog(@"File not exits");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do:

```
NSURL *imgPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"test" withExtension:@"png"];
NSString *path = [imgPath absoluteString];  
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:path];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSData* data =[[NSData alloc]init];
data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];
```

Answer (score 0):

After run:
file:///Users/xantatech/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/77F4D768-1F04-4390-B60F-F1FE79388653/data/Containers/Data/Application/**"87C457FA-1A9F-4CA9-A651-6A3D411A0B7E"**/Documents/myAudio0.mp3
The Bold text "87C457FA-1A9F-4CA9-A651-6A3D411A0B7E" may change;
You should always use the method to get the path in sandBox:

```
NSString *path = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myAudio0.mp3"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:yourURL];
```