# What is the Significance of Audiosession in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, playback, avaudiosession

I would like to know what is audiosession and why it should be used for audio playback. Can we play a sound without activating or initialing audiosession ?

Comment: What is your end goal? This question is very broad.

Comment: See [Play a short sound in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329291/play-a-short-sound-in-ios) for alternatives and pros/cons of different approaches.

Comment: I just want to know what is the theoretical concept behind audio-session. does audio-session deals with internal codec or handles memory? Why do we need to initialize audiosession or make it active and deactive ?