# Play audio file multiple times after a very short time?

Tags: ios, audio, avaudioplayer

I have an audio file that is 2 seconds long. Im trying to play that many times before it is done playing. But when I try it with AVAudioPlayer by creating a new instance of it, it sounds like it stops the audio that was played before and plays the new one instead of playing them at the same time. Should I use another way to play sounds or is this not achievable?

Code:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"PistolShootSound" withExtension:@"mp3"];
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
[audioPlayer play];
```

audioPlayer is declared in the header file.

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: What does your code look like? EDIT: You were faster :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you used `AVAudioPlayer's` property `numberOfLoops` to play audio file repeatedly?

**UPDATE**: I didn't understand your goal before. If you want to play short files many times you could use `AudioServices`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10336977/1990236) is a good example of how to use it.

Comment: Thats not what I want to do, this will loop the sound file I only want to play it once, its going to be the sound for a gun and guns can shoot very fast. If I put a loop for the sound it will play the sound when its not firing.

Comment: Nice it works like I want it now! Thank you sooooo much I want to upvote this 1 mil times :D