# UIButton Click sound not working?

Tags: ios, audio, uibutton, avfoundation

I have executed the following code ,but sound is not working.
in .h

```
 #import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
 #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

in .m

```
NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound1" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];

AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl];

[player play];
```

But I'm unable to hear any sound.Actually i wanted to manage button click sound along with volume button,so I'm using this method.

Comment: Which device are you using iPhone, iPod, iPad?

Comment: Are you configuring your applications audio session?

Comment: no,I'm not confirming ,what should i do and which protocol?

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the volume?

`[player setVolume:1.0];`

Another way to play a short sound is `AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID`.

See the link [Play a short sound in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329291/play-a-short-sound-in-ios)

Answer (score 1):

Try with :

```
 self.theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:(__bridge NSURL *)(soundUrl) error:NULL];

    self.theAudio.volume = 1.0;
    self.theAudio.delegate = self;
    [self.theAudio prepareToPlay];
    [self.theaudio play];
```

Answer (score 1):

This works perfect for me.

Add AVFoundation and AudioToolBox frameworks into the project

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface TestViewController : UIViewController
{
    SystemSoundID SoundID;
}

@implementation TestViewController
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"test" withExtension:@"caf"];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)url, &SoundID);  //When using ARC, make sure to use __bridge
 }

-(void) playSound {
     AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
 }
```