# iOS Simulator not playing sound effects

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, audiotoolbox

I know this question has been asked 999 times. All the answers say to go to *System Preferences* > *Sound* > *Sound Effects* and to make sure "Play user interface sound effects" is checked, or to uncheck and recheck it.

This does not work for me.  I have it checked but sound effects are still not playing.

Some more information:

1. I am trying to use `SystemSoundID` to play sound effects.
2. I previously used `AVAudioPlayer` for sound effects and it worked.
3. Went on YouTube from Safari in the simulator and video sound *did* play.
4. I have linked `AudioToolbox.framework` to my project.
5. I downloaded Apple sample code from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SysSound/Introduction/Intro.html).

This did not play either, so I am quite sure there is nothing wrong with my code.
6. I am running my Mac on Yosemite, OSx 10.10.1 with XCode 6.1.1.

I have not yet tested it on an actual device as I currently do not have a Developer's account. I do not wish to pay my life savings of $99 just to find out there was a box somewhere that I had left unchecked.

Is there anything else I should try?

My code:

**SoundEffect.h**

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>

@interface SoundEffect : NSObject
{
    SystemSoundID soundID;
}

- (id)initWithSoundNamed:(NSString *)filename withExtension:(NSString*) extension;

- (void)play;

@end
```

**SoundEffect.m**

```
#import "SoundEffect.h"

@implementation SoundEffect

- (id)initWithSoundNamed:(NSString *)filename withExtension:(NSString *)extension
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        NSURL *fileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:filename withExtension:extension];
        if (fileURL != nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"fileURL found");
            SystemSoundID theSoundID;
            OSStatus error = AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)fileURL, &theSoundID);
            if (error == kAudioServicesNoError)
                soundID = theSoundID;
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundID);
}

- (void)play
{
    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:soundEffectsKey]) {
        NSLog(@"Play sound effect");
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
    }else {
        NSLog(@"Sound effects are disabled");
    }
}
```

Note: I create this object and play it wherever I need to in my project. When I try to play my sounds, "fileURL found" and "Play sound effect" are both logged.

Source: [Play a short sound in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329291/play-a-short-sound-in-ios/10336977#10336977)

Comment: I don't mean to ask the obvious, but does your computer play other sounds?

Comment: Have you tried with a different sound file? you are calling

Comment: @RyanForsyth Yes, I've tried it with multiple sound files.

Comment: does the sound file play a sound when opened in Xcode?

Comment: What format is the audio file? and have you tried resetting simulator seeing if that helps?

Comment: mp3, and yes I have.

Comment: added the AudioToolbox.framework to build phases? Thats all I have left sorry as everything else says it should be working

Answer (score 0):

```
    SystemSoundID customSound;

NSString *soundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:<#customSoundName#> ofType:<#soundFormat#>];
    NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:openMenu];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)soundURL, & customSound);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(customSound);
```

This is works on mine