# Play audio file using EZAudio Framework in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, ezaudio

Hi I am trying to convert following Objective-C code to Swift:

```
EZAudioFile *audioFile = [EZAudioFile audioFileWithURL:NSURL]; //required type NSURL
[self.player playAudioFile:audioFile];
```

But I am unable to make it work.

```
let audioFile = EZAudioFile.url(EZAudioFile) //required type EZAudioFile, so I am unable to pass the NSURL of the audio file here.
player.play()
```

Error is : `Cannot convert value of type 'NSURL' to expected argument type 'EZAudioFile'`

The above objective-C code is referenced from here : [EZAudio Example:Record File](https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio/tree/master/EZAudioExamples/iOS/RecordFile)

Comment: I haven't used `EZAudioFile` but I have gotten `AVAudioPlayer` to work ok in Swift. Here is some code (scroll down in the answer) for reference. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32879428/3681880

Comment: I have done that in swift too. But the reason I am stuck to EZAudio is that I am using its one methods to create waveforms during recording. I am able to Record, Play the audio using AVAudioPlayer. So I thought It will be better to explore this framework(EZAudio) to use all its methods.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sounds interesting. I've wondered how some apps make wave forms. I hope you get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test, so I may be wrong, but I think you're not using the right syntax: `EZAudioFile.url(EZAudioFile)` does not call the initializer you're thinking of.

I see [in the EZAudioFile source](https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio/blob/master/EZAudio/EZAudioFile.m#L136) that there's indeed an initializer for an audio file URL:

> `+ (instancetype)audioFileWithURL:(NSURL *)url`

So my guess is that the syntax in Swift should rather be:

```
let audioFile = EZAudioFile(audioFileWithURL: yourURL)
```

Also, it seems that it is only a wrapper for the normal URL init, which should be something like:

```
let audioFile = EZAudioFile(URL: yourURL)
```

Comment: Spot On! The Xcode autocompletion caught me here. 
What will be the replacement of `[self.player playAudioFile:audioFile];` in Swift?

Comment: It should be [similar](https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio/blob/master/EZAudio/EZAudioPlayer.m#L334): `self.player.playAudioFile(audioFile)` I suppose (again, just a guess while reading the source since I don't have access to an EZ install right now).

Comment: Very tricky swift conversion. It came out to be: `player = EZAudioPlayer(EZAudioFile:audioFile)`. Thank you for your helpful comments!!